# Adding shapefile directly to geoserver

Tags: python, postgis, geoserver

I have py script which is creating shapefiles using [shapefile.py](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/). Once the shapefile is created I have to add them manually to the geoserver. Is there a way to add it dynamically to the geoserver? through postgis or something?

**UPDATE**

Ok so seems my project manager has changed his plan, he wants me to add the shapefiles to the PostGIS Database which will update the newly added shapefiles to the geoserver where there will be a connection to the PostGIS Database. Is it possible to update the newly added shapefiles to reflect in the Geoserver?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the REST API of GeoServer.

> The REST extension provides a RESTful interface through which clients
>   can configure a GeoServer instance through simple HTTP calls. With it
>   clients can programatically configure the data served by GeoServer.

This [example](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-examples-curl.html#uploading-a-shapefile) explains how to upload a shapefile in GeoServer using cURL.

Answer (score 2):

with python there are some scripts about shp to geoserver... you can check out them for your needs. They will help you to make this work(from [here](http://blog.geoserver.org/2008/09/05/batch-importing-shapefiles/)):

```
Copied a shapefile (and associated files) to the data directory
Appended info block to catalog.xml
Created named FeatureType directory and associated info.xml
```

1.[shp2geoserver.py](http://blog.geoserver.org/wp-content/uploads/shp2geoserver.py)

2.[shapefilebatch-cleaned.py](http://blog.geoserver.org/wp-content/uploads/shapefilebatch-cleaned.py)

i hope it helps you...

Comment: hi @Aragon, i know it has been a long time but should I simply `import shp2geoserver.py` in my py script and provide the `(shp,featureid,sld,srs)`? How do I use the shapefilebatch-cleaned.py?

Answer (score 0):

You could of course add your shapefile to postGIS using, for example, ogr2ogr ( http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html ).

If you append your data to an existing table the data should be included in the geoserver layer you've made for the table. If you are creating a new table (possibly what you are doing, since schemas will vary from shapefile to shapefile, you could use the beforementioned REST api to add the new table as a layer (provided that you have the datastore set up). See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html#adding-a-postgis-table